# POST Request gives timeout when testing on iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, laravel, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm working on a school project, which is developing a Web application with an API and an iPhone app with swift. I developed the website in Laravel with Homestead/Vagrant.

But when it comes to the iPhone app, i'm facing with a problem:
When a user presses the login button the app sends a http POST request to the API and the API checks if the users exists in the db, if so then it will return a token, after which the user will be redirected to the dashboard. This works fine on the xcode simulator.

My code of the request part looks like this:

```
var loginUrl = "http://10.1.1.33/api/login" + "?email=" + self.email + "&password=" + self.password

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: loginUrl)!)

            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
                data, response, error -> Void in

                guard error == nil else {
                    print("First Error!!! \(error)")
                    self.errorLabel.text = "Request timed Out"
                    self.enableLoginBtn(true, buttonText: "Login")

                    return
                }

                do {
                    let data: AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
                    // Okay, the `json` is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it

                    let json = JSON(data!)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        if json["token"] != nil {

                            print("Login successvol!)")


                            if self.saveSession(json["token"].string!) {
                                self.enableLoginBtn(true, buttonText: "Login")
                                self.goToDashboard()
                            }else {
                                print("Saving token went wrong")
                            }


                        }else {
                            self.showError("Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord is onjuist")
                            self.enableLoginBtn(true, buttonText: "Login")
                        }

                    })


                }catch let parseError{
                    print(parseError)
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                    self.enableLoginBtn(true, buttonText: "Login")
                }
            })

            task.resume()
```

But when i try to test the exact same thing on my iPhone 5s (I have a developer license) it's failing every single time. The error i'm getting is:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1742e1e80 {NSUnderlyingError=0x170259230 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1001.)",
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://10.1.1.33/api/login?email=jejz@kdk.nl&password=sndxbdj,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://10.1.1.33/api/login?email=jejz@kdk.nl&password=sndxbdj,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

The last couple days i searched the whole internet for a solution, but i couldn't find any solution.

I'd be really grateful if someone can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

EDITED ---------------------
**Screenshot of the error**
[image]

Comment: Maybe the problem is something to do with the network? Does you development mac reaches the server via Wifi as well, like your phone?

Comment: My mac reaches the server. It works like a charm. But when it comes to testing it on my iPhone, it fails

Comment: Do you have any standard HTML pages on your website at 10.1.1.33? Can you see them okay in the browser on your phone?

Comment: Everything on the website works fine aswell, even if i make a POST request with url paramters as Dejan Skledar explains below.

Comment: it it blocked and you need to provide ur id to whitelist? try creating a hotspot on your mac machine and connect your iPhone to that hotspot and try

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot I will try your alternative when to solution below doesn't work. I'm going to test it now.

Comment: @OsmanSafaKaya did you try it?

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot Creating a hotspot on my mac didn't work, my phone couldn't find the hotspot of my mac. So i wasn't be able to test the app. I really appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be confused about POST and GET requests.

**POST** parameters are sent in the **Request body**, while in the **GET** request the parameters are sent in the **URL**.

#### GET Method parameters example:

```
/test/demo_form.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

#### POST Method parameters example:

```
POST /test/demo_form.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: w3schools.com
name1=value1&name2=value2
```

So what you are trying to do, is send the parameters in the **URL** with the **POST** request, which is why it doesn't work!

You need to put the parameters in the **Request body**!

### What you need to do is:

#### 1. Change the request URL

```
var loginUrl = "http://10.1.1.33/api/login"
```

#### 2. Add the parameters in the Request body

```
let postString = "email=" + self.email + "&password=" + self.password
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

Comment: This is entirely true, and good advice, but I'm not sure it explains the actual issue in the question, i.e. the network timeout.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That makes really sense... I'm heading to the airport now, you will hear from me ASAP when i test your code

Comment: @MattGibson Yes, this really shouldn't timeout, but we don't know how the server is configured. Its definitely a start.

Comment: @DejanSkledar Sorry that it took so long. Just came back and tested immediately the solution you wrote. But unfortunately it doesn't work on my device. It does in the simulator. I added a screenshot of the error i'm getting when i run it on my device.

Comment: Try to ping the server or access the server over Postman, to check if the server works as it should

Comment: Are you with your phone on the same network as with your mac? Try to ping the server from the phone

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 9, this is due to the new Transport security setting that is enabled by default. It blocks all outgoing non https requests. There is a way to turn it off for all requests, so any http request will load. There is also a way to control each url or url wildcard that can load on http.

If you are using http for your login, I suggest you change your server to support SSL and TLS 2.0 (pretty much the standard on most hosts with https) rather than turning it off to load http. Usernames and passwords shouldnt go over http.

If however you need to turn it off for furthering the development until you get a certificate setup, here is how to do it.

Add this to your info.plist file (open it in source code mode, control click on the file and select)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

If you want to control specific urls, you can use `<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>`

Comment: I already added the above code to my info.plist at the beginning. Because it didn't work in the beginning in my simulator, but after i added the code above it did work, but only in my simulator. I will do a research to change my homestead server to support SSL.